# 17 year old trying to get back to US, with dual citizenship in Australia

Tags: international-travel, us-citizens, australian-citizens, minors

I am a 17 year old in Australia trying to go back to the US. If I have citizenship for both Australia and the US am I allowed to travel back alone without my parents’ permission? Is there any way I can be excused if not

Comment: Do you have a US passport?

Comment: To some extent, what you will need to present depends on the airline. [Qantas](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/travel-info/children/unaccompanied.html#essential-travel-documentation), for example, requires you submit in advance the full name and contact details of an "authorising adult" and the same for the adult who will be receiving the minor at the final destination. If you are trying to leave because of a bad situation at home, I would strongly advise you to first seek assistance in Australia, as traveling to a different country adds another layer of risks and complications.

Comment: You may want to apply for emancipation first. https://yla.org.au/wa/topics/at-home-parents-and-family/ Will you be traveling with a friend? Or will that friend be paying for your plane ticket? If that friend is an adult, that friend could be charged with trafficking a minor.

Answer (score 34):

There are currently restrictions in place for Australians (including dual citizens) leaving the country.

https://covid19.homeaffairs.gov.au/leaving-australia#toc-1

> If you are an Australian citizen or a permanent resident you cannot leave Australia due to COVID-19 restrictions unless you have an exemption. You can apply online but you must meet at least one of the following:
>
> - your travel is as part of the response to the COVID-19 outbreak,
>   including the provision of aid
> - your travel is essential for the conduct of critical industries and business (including export and import industries)
> - you are travelling to receive urgent medical treatment that is not available in Australia
> - you are travelling on urgent and unavoidable personal business
> - you are travelling on compassionate or humanitarian grounds
> - your travel is in the national interest.
>
> An exemption may apply if you aren't normally resident in Australia.
>
> You are considered ordinarily resident in a country other than Australia if international movement records show that you’ve spent more time outside Australia than inside for the last 12 to 24 months. You do not need to carry a paper record of your movements with you. If required, Australian Border Force officers at airports can check your movement records in Departmental systems.
>
> If you have not spent more time outside Australia than inside for the last 12 to 24 months, but still consider yourself to be ordinarily resident in another country, you can submit a request for a travel exemption.

Comment: Further down, seems like dual citizens can argue to leave `evidence that you are a dual national or hold a valid visa for another country` and https://au.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/ Dual citizens can apply for exception.

Answer (score 30):

My kids have frequently traveled to the US on their own when they where minors without any type of special paperwork. No one ever asked for a travel permit or Guardian consent form.

However there are a few caveats

1. You need a to book a flight and someone needs to pay for it. The ticket must be in your name and you may have to prove that the booking is legit, which in some cases requires you to present the credit card used to buy the ticket at check in. Rules vary a lot between different airlines.
2. Some airlines may require a guardian consent form. Check with the airline, rules vary a lot.
3. You need a valid US passport. No airline will allow you to board a US bound flight without a valid US passport.
4. You may get snagged in exit control if your name shows up in the system as "reported missing" or "run-away", i.e. if your parents/guardians reported you to the authorities for one reason or another.
5. On the customs form you need to provide the address you will be staying in the US. For a minor they may a look a little closer whether that address makes sense.
6. You will get interviewed when you enter the US. They may ask you why you are travelling, where you are going, what you will be doing, where you will be staying etc. As a US citizen, they can't deny you entry but they may alert social services if they don't like the answers.

Obviously by far the safest choice here is to get agreement and permission from at least one guardian or parent. If that's not possible, you may want to reach out for help locally. Travelling adds to the complications.

Comment: "No airline will allow you to board a US bound flight without a valid US passport." That's surely not true. Do you mean a US passport or a visa/entry permit"?

Comment: @curiousdannii Visas aren't issued to dual US citizens, nor are usually ESTAs

Comment: @curiousdannii I read "you" in the answer as referring to the OP, a US citizen, not as referring to all readers.

Comment: US citizens don't need to fill out a customs form and aren't interviewed on entry. At least, I don't think I did either last time I visited the US, although it's been a few years. Perhaps the rules are different for minors or have changed? If not, I believe your points 5 and 6 aren't relevant here.

Comment: @terdon my wife, US citizen with double citizenship, was interviewed about two years ago. She was no minor of course. Do you have another citizenship as well?

Comment: I do, yes but I when I travel to the US, I use my US passport. I have been to the US around 6-7 times or so and have never been interviewed. Unless by "interview" you mean the standard 20-second chat you have with all border agents ("business or pleasure?"). I've never had an actual _interview_.

Comment: @terdon it was much longer than 20 seconds, but still rather swift. What kept you away from the homeland for so long, etc

Comment: @terdon: US citizens must fill out a customs declaration form on returning to the US unless you have Global Entry. Global Entry is currently disabled in some airport (EWR last week, for example). By "interview" I mean: the agent may ask you a few questions. The extend and depth of these questions vary wildly and are unpredictable. A minor travelling alone will likely trigger more intense questioning than a frequent business flyer.

Comment: @Hilmar my bad, I misunderstood and thought you were referring to the landing card required of non-citizens. And OK, fair enough. I wouldn't have thought of this as an "interview", it's been so perfunctory in my experience, but you make a good point about a minor likely attracting more scrutiny. I don't remember having any issues when I did this as a minor but that was around 25 years ago now, so I wouldn't take my word for it either :)

Comment: @terdon the immigration officer also considers whether to select the traveler for customs inspection, which is why they want to know about the purpose of the trip.  And of course they can ask questions to try to expose a fraudulent claim of US citizenship (for example, perhaps the passport actually belongs to the traveler's identical twin or even a non-identical relative).